# Printing problem with Canon MG6200 after upgrading to Ubuntu 20.04

Tags: printing, 20.04

Since I upgraded my system to Ubuntu 20.04, I cannot print anymore:

```
$ lpq
MG6200 est prêt
no entries

$ lpr feuille.pdf
lpr : Unsupported document-format "application/pdf".
```

I restarted cups, reinstalled the printers (wifi and usb)
What else can I try?

Answer (score 0):

Try methods described [here](http://ubuntuhandbook.org/index.php/2018/10/canon-ij-printer-scangear-mp-drivers-ubuntu-18-04-18-10/) and tell if it helped or not:

sudo add-apt-repository ppa:thierry-f/fork-michael-gruz
sudo apt install cnijfilter2 scangearmp2 cndrvcups-utility

> Depends on your device, search for cnijfilter (for printing) or
>   scangearmp (for scanning) in Synaptic package manager (install it via
>   Ubuntu Software).
>
> And finally select install the driver that is match for your device.
>   And it’s OK to install i386 only package on 64-bit Ubuntu.

If these packages have been installed, uninstall them:

```
sudo apt purge cnijfilter2 scangearmp2 cndrvcups-utility && sudo apt autoremove
```

and try again.

During upgrade kernel and some system libs have been changed. So it could be the main cause of your issue.

Comment: So far I failed. The package cndrvcups-utility does not exist. The two others cnijfilter2 scangearmp2 did install properly. I still get the same error. It seems that the printer (USB or Network) is not installed with the adequate packages. Thanks for your support.

Answer (score 0):

1. Remove `ippusbxd` by running this command in terminal:

   ```
   sudo apt remove ippusbxd
   ```
2. Delete and reinstall the printer using the GUI printer utility
3. Print a test page

This worked for me after hours of troubleshooting, I hope it works for you as well!

You might also want to read these related questions where more knowledgeable people than me explain how all printers now are "network printers" or something like that. Apparently removing `ippusbxd` isn't the most elegant solution, but as long as it works I'm happy :-)

- [Getting HP DeskJet 3700 working with Xubuntu 20.04](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1264255/getting-hp-deskjet-3700-working-with-xubuntu-20-04)
- [Canon PIXMA MP230 doesn't work with Ubuntu 20.04](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1248948/canon-pixma-mp230-doesnt-work-with-ubuntu-20-04)